# Popups showing only once per page

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone help me?

I have a pop up on a page and I only want it to show once. I also have another popup on another page running the same code.

What would be the best way to make it so that each pop up only shows once, but on there own page?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('popupState') != 'shown'){
        $("#voucherForm").delay(10000).fadeIn();
        $("#signupcover").delay(10000).fadeIn();
        localStorage.setItem('popupState','shown');
    }
});

$("#popup-close").click(function() {
  $("#voucherForm").removeAttr( 'style' );
});
```

Comment: Well you might probably want to start by storing not just one single value into localStorage, but one for each popup.

Comment: I need to make this dynamic, as the code is added using a module/block in the CMS so could go 10 times on different pages

Comment: What part(s) of this do you need to make “dynamic”? This still needs a better explanation of what the actual issue is here, IMHO.

Comment: I am guessing the "popupState" needs to be so that anytime this is run on a page it knows to only do it once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different local storage variables, i.e. localStorage.getItem('popup1_State') and localStorage.getItem('popup2_State')

Comment: This is what I was thinking but it would need to be dynamic as the code is added using a module/block in the CMS so could go 10 times on different pages

Is there a way I can check to see if the popupState has a value of shown then add an intarational number to the end of it so it goes popupState1, popupState2, popupState3

Comment: So, make the name of the variable dynamic based on some kind of the module/block id

Comment: So i could add a var "pageID" and then pass that into the localStorage.getItem('popup_State' + pageID)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, use different variables to control the pop-ups depending on the multiple page address.

```
switch(location.href) {
   case page1:
     const isPop = locaStorage.getItem('page1');
     if(isPop) {
       popFormOfPage1.pop();
       locaStorage.setItem('page1', false);
     }
     break;
   case page2:
     // same case1
   default:
     // do something
}
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any code in your answer. Was this a mistake?